# Case statement to change UILabel depending on UISlider value

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uilabel, uislider

So, straight in to it. I wish to change the value of a label depending on the position of the UISlider. If the slider is in position 1, and untouched, the label should show "Regular", at value 2 it should show "Soy" and value 3, "Almond".

In case you hadn't guessed already, it is to make a milk choice.

Ideally I wish to use a switch/case. The slider has a minimum value of 1 which refers to regular milk. The aim for the app is to use the cloud down the line to save order information, so I am open as to which would be the best solution complying to this future requirement.

Thanks!

Currently....

```
@IBOutlet weak var sugarValue: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var sugarStepper: UIStepper!

@IBOutlet weak var milkChoice: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var milkChoiceSlider: UISlider!

@IBAction func sugarChange(sender: UIStepper) {
    sugarValue.text = Double(sugarStepper.value).description
}

@IBAction func milkChoiceChange(sender: UISlider) {
    milkChoice.text = String(milkChoiceSlider.value)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I'm aware that the current set up would not show the text in the label, I was trying to just get it to show the 1, 2, 3 values first but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet... As you see, you can use an array of values, in this case you don't need "case" :)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var milkChoiceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var milkChoiceSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet var sugarValue: UILabel!

    var labelValues: [String] = ["Regular", "Soy", "Almond"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

        sender.value = roundf(sender.value)

        let value = Int(sender.value)

        sugarValue.text = value.description

//        switch (sender.value) {
//        case 1:
//            milkChoiceLabel.text = labelValues[0]
//            break
//        case 2:
//            milkChoiceLabel.text = labelValues[1]
//            break
//        case 3:
//            milkChoiceLabel.text = labelValues[2]
//            break
//        default:
//            break
//        }

        // or better ...

        milkChoiceLabel.text = labelValues[value - 1];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real problem here is that you're misusing a UISlider as a tri-state switch. A slider is *continuous*; it's not a switch. If you wanted a tri-state switch, you should *use* a tri-state switch, namely a UISegmentedControl.